# Silverlight TabItem header hide

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol

Is it possible (in XAML) to hide the headers of the tab items in a tab control in Silverlight (preferably Silverlight 4)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this before by copying the out-of-the-box MS template, and edited that copied template to affect whatever changes were needed, such as hiding elements.  Then I applied this new template to the control.

Here is a link to the Silverlight 3 [tab control templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035%28VS.95%29.aspx).  I don't know if they are the same for SL 4.

Comment: Worked as you proposed!Thanks very much .

Comment: Glad to here it.  Good luck with your project.